# LaTeX equation/align formating issue

Tags: math-mode

This doesn't seem to work

```
\begin {align}
f(x^2-3x+2}+2f(x^2+x)&=9x^2-3x-6 \\
-f{2x^2-2x)-4f(x^2-3x+2)&=-18x^2+30x \\
-3f(x^2-3x+2)&=-9x^2+27x-6 \\
f(x^2-3x+2)&=3x^2-9x+2
\end {align}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code we can compile (a minimal example) rather than a fragment. What does 'doesn't seem to work' mean? Do you get an error? What is the exact text? Do you get unexpected output? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: Sorry! The error is:(The line is the first given) Argument of \align has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.23 f(x^2-3x+2}
                +2f(x^2+x)&=9x^2-3x-6 \\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You twice put braces where you meant brackets: line 1 has `}` and line 2 has `{`.  This works:

```
\begin {align}
f(x^2-3x+2)+2f(x^2+x)&=9x^2-3x-6 \\
-f(2x^2-2x)-4f(x^2-3x+2)&=-18x^2+30x \\
-3f(x^2-3x+2)&=-9x^2+27x-6 \\
f(x^2-3x+2)&=3x^2-9x+2
\end {align}
```